# Java : Json exception

Tags: java, java-me

I am working in J2ME.

I am getting json response from server then I try to parse this json data as per my requirement.

this is my code for getting response from server:-

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStreamWriter out = null;
        byte[] readData = new byte[50000];

        String response = "no";

try {
            // --- write ---
            out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.openOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
            out.write(data.toString());
            out.close();
            // --- read ---

            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode != HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                throw new IOException("HTTP response code: " + responseCode);
            }

            inputStream = connection.openInputStream();

            int actual = inputStream.read(readData);


            response = new String(readData, 0, actual, "UTF-8");

            return response;

        }
```

when response from server is small then it works fine, but if response is large then it get half of response and return to my another method. Please suggest me what should I do to get large amount of data into my **readData** and **response** variable.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to read **all data before** (there can be more data in the stream).

As you have noticed the call to `InputStream.read` doesn't guarantee you to fill your buffer (`readData`) it return the number of bytes it could read at the time. It just doesn't matter how big your buffer is on your side.

You will need to read re-call the `InputStream.read` method to check that you have all the data available in the stream. The `read` method will return `-1` when no more data is available.

---

This is an example how you can do it:

```
....

ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int read;
byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
while ((read = inputStream.read(tmp)) != -1)
    bos.write(tmp, 0, read);

return new String(bos.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
```

---

*Also, when you are done with the `connection` you should call `close` on it so that the system knows that you don't need it anymore.*

Comment: Then how can I do this..? should I add some more memory bytes for  byte[] readData = new byte[50000];  ?

Comment: @PushpendraKuntal: Updated with example :)

Answer (score 0):

You nead to flush and close your input stream after reading!!!

```
inputStream.close();
```

Comment: There is no `flush` method on `InputStream` (I think you confuse it with `OutputStream`).

Comment: Closing, however, wont help you getting any more input, thats just to clean up afterwards...